# Looking for a word that describes when you say both possible outcomes

Tags: vocabulary

Sometimes someone will say "if we don't win, we lose" or "we will make it, or we won't" or another example is, "if i don't pass, I fail"

It is when someone needlessly states the obvious alternative.

I have heard the word before, but now just cannot recall it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A tautology perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to a [pleonasm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pleonastic):(adj) *pleonastic*:

> - The use of more words than are required to express an idea; redundancy.
> - A superfluous word or phrase.
>
> Adj.  pleonastic - repetition of same sense in different words; *a true fact  and ` free gift are pleonastic expressions"*;
> "the phrase a beginner who has just started' is *tautological or redundant*"

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pleonastic

Comment: And for the examples given, a *dichotomous pleonasm* (or *pleonastic dichotomy*).